# Ternary operator inside printf

Tags: c, syntax, printf, conditional-operator

After reading [this](http://byuh.doncolton.com/courses/tut/printf.pdf) I started thinking that I have learned a loot about `printf()`. Suddenly I found following code snippet from [this](http://www.flipkart.com/test-your-c-skills-5th/p/itmdyuqz4xg8sfxd) book:

```
int main()
{
    char str[]="Hello";
    int i=5,j=10;
    printf(i>j?"%50s":"%s",str); //unable to understand this 
    return 0;
}
```

Surprisingly above code is running without errors and it prints Hello.
As per my knowledge following is syntax of `printf()`:

```
int printf(const char *format,argument_list);
```

So according to this syntax, `printf()` should start with format string. But as you can see in above code `printf()` is starting with `i>j`.
**Does it mean I am wrong in interpreting syntax of printf()?
Does placing ternary operator inside printf() is a special case?**

**EDIT**

I know about ternary operator I am asking about first argument of `printf()` which should be const char* which I seem not in my example.

Comment: The result of the expression inside the 1st parameter must be a pointer to a constant char array, so nothing surprising.

Comment: you mean anything even without double quotes is pointer to constant string

Comment: maybe things get clearer if you write it this way: `printf((i>j?"%50s":"%s"), str)`

Comment: @A.s.Bhullar both `"%50s"` and `"%s"` are in fact pointers to constant char arrays. `i>j?"%50s":"%s"` is an expression. The result of that expression must be a pointer to a constant char array. I think you are confusing a `const char *` with a constant expression, which are not the same thing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The conditional operator:

```
i>j?"%50s":"%s"
```

is an expression and it has to be evaluated before the function call itself can be evaluated. We can see this by going to the draft C99 standard section `6.5.2.2` *Function calls* which says:

> An argument may be an expression of any object type. In preparing for
>   the call to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each
>   parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument.<sup>81)</sup>

So what is the result of the evaluation of the conditional operator? If we go to section `6.5.15` *Conditional operator* it says (*emphasis mine*):

> The first operand is evaluated; there is a sequence point after its
>   evaluation. The second operand is evaluated only if the first compares
>   unequal to 0; the third operand is evaluated only if the first
>   compares equal to 0; **the result is the value of the second or third
>   operand (whichever is evaluated)**, converted to the type described
>   below.<sup>95</sup>

so in either case the result is a string literal which will decay to pointer to char which satisfies the requirement for the first argument to `printf`.

Comment: Nice explantion!!
But I have still doubt in expression i>j?"%50s":"%s" that is I don't think it is const char* ,I think it should enclosed in double quotes marks. Isn't is?

Comment: Ok now I understand it
that is after evaluating expression only "%s" is passed as a argument to printf()

Answer (score 4):

This code is normal and is not any special case. The requirement for `printf` is that the first argument should be of the type `const char*`, but it does not necessarily mean that it needs to be a string literal like `"%s"`. All it means that you need to pass as the first argument an expression of the type `const char*`. And `i>j?"%50s":"%s"` fulfils this requirement.

Comment: Can you plz give any example of const char* which is not fully wrapped inside double quotes?

Comment: `i>j?"%50s":"%s"` is of type `const char *` (technically it is `const char []` but it does not matter here) so I guess this is your example. Another example would be `func()`, where `func` is a function returning `const char*`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you well understood the `printf` syntax but i think you are missing something about C syntax.

It exist a form of "compact IF like" statement formatted like that : ( *condition* ? *true* : *false* )

For example you can do :

```
int a=5;
int b=(a==5 ? 128 : 256);
int c=(a!=5 ? 8 : 9);
```

In this case, b=128 and c=9.

An other example :

```
int flag=1;
printf("The value is: %s", (flag!=0 ? "true" : "false) );
```

In this case you can see : *The value is true*

On your example :

```
printf(i>j?"%50s":"%s",str);
```

if i is upper than j you use "%50s" format and, if i is lower you use "%s" format

It can be view like  :

```
if (i>j)
    printf("%50s",str);
else
    printf("%s",str);
```

You can see the advantage of compact test.

Answer (score 2):

It is a ternary operator and in this the condition i>j is false so %s will be passed as parameter to printf which will print the value of character array which is hello.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean I am wrong in interpreting syntax of printf()?

No you are not interpreting it wrong.

> Does placing ternary operator inside printf() is a special case?

In C, you can say that its an expression instead of a statement

Your code is equivalent to:

```
if (i > j)
    printf("%50s", str);
else
    printf("%s", str);
```

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator is simply an inline `if` that's used as an expression (while a regular `if` is used to create a block). Your line is equal to this:

```
if (i > j)
    printf("%50s", str);
else
    printf("%s", str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(i>j)
    printf("%50s",str);
else
    printf("%s",str);
```

Therefore, `Hello` gets printed in both situations

Answer (score 1):

Q: Does it mean I am wrong in interpreting syntax of printf()?
A: No, just need to expand what is allowable.

Q: Does placing ternary operator inside printf() is a special case?
A: No `?:` is not special, but sometimes confusing at first glance.

The format supplied to `printf()` does not need to be a literal.  It may be any string variable.

```
int main() {
  char str[]="Hello";
  char *format;
  int i,j;

  i = 5; j = 10; 
  format = i > j ? "%50s" : "%s";
  printf(format, str);

  i = 10; j = 5; 
  format = i > j ? "%50s" : "%s";
  printf(format, str);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a statement of the form: condition?consequent:alternative.

The condition is checked, and if it's true you'll get the consequent. otherwise you'll get the alternative.

For example:

```
5>3 ? 10 : 5
```

5>3 is true, so you'll get 10.